# Manual Elmah logging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

how I can use Elmah logger only when I want?
I have ErrorsController and I need log it only when excpetion is unknown:

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception(string.Format("{0}, {1}", controller, action), exception));
```

I didn't implement ElmahAttributes, Elmah added only in web.config.
How I can do that? I have idea to use some errorFilter that will filter all incoming errors, but it's not very good, I think.

**UPD**

I have add filter that ignores all errors:

```
<errorFilter>
  <ignoreAll>
      <regex binding="Context.Request.Url" pattern="." />
  </ignoreAll>
</errorFilter>
```

but it ignores absolutely everything, even that I call to log manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand why filter ignores error - because when using `Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise()` we are "emulate" process of getting error and this errors fall under the filter.
Instead of this method we should use Elmah logger method to add error to log:

```
Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(System.Web.HttpContext.Current).Log()
```

This method will add error to log and filter below will ignore all others:

```
<errorFilter>
  <test>
    <regex binding="Context.Request.Url" pattern="." />
  </test>
</errorFilter>
```

After all this I have one question - name tag inside `<errorFilter>` can only be `test`?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it in `Web.Config` file. Check [this wiki](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering)

Comment: Sorry, but this article about filtering, I said that I want to find another way to ignore all errors. If it possible, ofcourse.

Comment: @Boo yep it ignores other exceptions

Comment: Can you help me with this filter? I try, but there is only HttpExceptions has HttpStatusCode, how I can filter all errors?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `<add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>` at `httpModules` section. I create filter, but it ignores all errors. See my post update

Comment: @Boo you can use the `JScript` filtering to filter by exception type.

Comment: Thanks, I know. [Here is](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFilterExamples) few examples of filters